# Bind attribute only once (like bindonce)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components, bindonce

On a [component](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) is it possible to bind in the style like [bindonce](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce)? Please provide an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since angular have v1.3 it used following syntax for bindonce

```
<div ng-repeat="item in ctrl.results">
    <div>{{ ::item.name }} - {{ ::item.description }}</div>
</div>
<div ng-if="::vm.user.loggedIn"></div>
for class
ng-class="::{ loggedIn: vm.user.loggedIn }"
```

Comment: You are right, here's the doc: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression, section "One time binding".